# Google Analytics Not working in an iframe on https

Tags: google-analytics

We have an tracking issue when our page is iframed.

Basically, we have a website: `https://www.ourwebsite.com`

Our website contains the following code in the `head` section:

```
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
    
        ga('create', {
            trackingId: "UA-FOOBAR-1",
            cookieDomain: 'auto',
            tenantCode: "someString"
        });
        
        ga('send', 'pageview');
```

This works fine, and I see a corresponding request to `https://www.google-analytics.com/j/collect` when the page load:

[Screenshot of Chrome Network Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvfy0.png)

However, when this same page is in an iframe:

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="https://www.ourwebsite.com" scrolling="no" style="width: 100% !important; min-width: 100% !important; overflow: hidden;"></iframe>
```

The request to the google analytics `/collect` endpoint is missing from the Chrome Network Tab, and we do not see the pageview event in the browser.

If the iframe `src` is changed from `https` to `http`, I start seeing reqeusts to `/collect` again.

The parent document is using the same scheme as the iframe (uses `https` when the iframe uses `https`, and uses `http` when the iframe is on `http`)

Full page source of `ourwebsite.com`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
<script>
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
    
        ga('create', {
            trackingId: "UA-FOOBAR-1",
            cookieDomain: 'auto',
            tenantCode: "someString"
        });
        
        ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
    </head>
    <body class="ui-mobile">
            
    </body>
</html>
```